# Why my torch geometric test function always returns the same accuracy metric?

Tags: machine-learning, testing, torch, graph-neural-network

I am using torch geometric to train a GCN, my problem is that my test() function always returns the same accuracy metric, it seems like the model is not updating itself during training. However I did see the binary cross entropy loss decrease from 0.6 to 0.2 during training. I am confused.

I tried to convert a tabular dataset downloaded from kaggle and convert it to be a Data object in torch geometric like this:

```
from torch_geometric.data import Data
data = Data(x=tensor_x, edge_index=edge_index, y=tensor_y)
```

Then I use this code to train a graph convolutional neural network:

```
model = GCN()
model.eval()

_, h = model(data.x, data.edge_index)
print(f'Embedding shape: {list(h.shape)}')

visualize_embedding(h, color=data.y)

import time
from IPython.display import Javascript  # Restrict height of output cell.
display(Javascript('''google.colab.output.setIframeHeight(0, true, {maxHeight: 430})'''))

model = GCN()

criterion = torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()# Define loss criterion.
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(),lr=0.01, weight_decay=5e-4)  # Define optimizer.

def train():
    model.train()
    optimizer.zero_grad()  # Clear gradients.
    out, h = model(data.x, data.edge_index)  # Perform a single forward pass.
    loss = criterion(out[data.train_mask], data.y[data.train_mask])  # Compute the loss solely based on the training nodes.
    loss.backward()  # Derive gradients.
    optimizer.step()  # Update parameters based on gradients.
    return loss, h

def test():
    model.eval()
    out,_ = model(data.x, data.edge_index)
    pred = out.argmax(dim=1)  # Use the class with highest probability.
    pred_test = pred[data.test_mask]
    GT = torch.squeeze(data.y[data.test_mask]) 
    test_correct = (pred_test == GT)  # Check against ground-truth labels.
    test_acc = int(test_correct.sum()) / int(data.test_mask.sum())  # Derive ratio of correct predictions.
    return test_acc

for epoch in range(2001):    
    loss, h, acc = train()
    if epoch % 100 == 0:
        visualize_embedding(h, color=data.y, epoch=epoch, loss=loss)
        time.sleep(0.3)

acc = test()
acc
```

I expect the accracy will drop after training the GCN. Tha's all I want. Since the binary crossentropy is only 0.2, it's not very close to zero. Hence I won't expect the accuracy be very very high. However, I would hope I can see after the training, the accuracy gets higher. Now it's always a fixed value

By the way, the GCN model code is here:

```
import torch
from torch.nn import Linear
from torch_geometric.nn import GCNConv


class GCN(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        torch.manual_seed(1234)
        self.conv1 = GCNConv(data.num_features, 4)
        self.conv2 = GCNConv(4, 4)
        self.conv3 = GCNConv(4, 4)
        self.conv4 = GCNConv(4, 4)
        self.conv5 = GCNConv(4, 2)
        self.classifier = Linear(2, 1)

    def forward(self, x, edge_index):
        h = self.conv1(x, edge_index)
        h = h.tanh()
        h = self.conv2(h, edge_index)
        h = h.tanh()
        h = self.conv3(h, edge_index)
        h = h.tanh()  
        h = self.conv4(h, edge_index)
        h = h.tanh()
        h = self.conv5(h, edge_index)
        h = h.tanh()
        # Apply a final (linear) classifier.
        out = self.classifier(h)

        return out, h

model = GCN()
print(model)`
```

Comment: I understand this is not normally how people play with graph neural networks. I just want to see if I can convert a tabular dataset into graph format and train, it and test it. Besides, this is the ipynb of the code: [link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Q0bAKK6PRo5ECBBBaw7DNuyBUFsLXFOV?usp=sharing). I will definitely appreciate anyone who can give me some help. I have tried to search for a solution online for quite some time. Desperate...